# Is there a way to generate a unique resource name in AEM?

Tags: model, osgi, sling, sightly, aem-6

I've created a table with a list inside tbody. It will generate a number of rows. However, I have to make the `resource name` unique every row. Any ideas on this?

```
    <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-sly-list="${itemCount}">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div data-sly-resource="${'resourceName' @ resourceType='components/content/mycomponent'}"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I get what you plan to do there. It seems you want to generated unique synthetic resource names.

For that you could use `itemList.count` or `itemList.index` to have values such as: `res1`, `res2` ... or `res0`, `res1` ... See [details in the HTL specification](https://github.com/adobe/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#226-list).

You would probably have to use `data-sly-set` to concatenate the number to the text:

```
        <tbody data-sly-list="${itemCount}">
            <tr>
                <td data-sly-set.resourceName="res${itemList.count}">
                    <div data-sly-resource="${resourceName @ resourceType='components/content/mycomponent'}"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```